# Meaning of these particular pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, steganography

I'm hesitant to consider this a valid question so close or downvote if you wish, I promise not to be offended :-)

I've just been watching [Herb Sutter's excellent CppCon2018 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80BZxujhY38) on making C++ more powerful and simpler at the same time. I'd strongly suggest watching this if you haven't already.

Near the end, he references [an xkcd cartoon](https://xkcd.com/138/) on pointers, where the three pointers given are suspiciously ASCII in nature<sup>(a)</sup>, usually a sure sign that you've somehow got yourself a corrupt pointer.

The three pointers are `0x3a28213a`, `0x6339392c` and `0x7363682e`, which equate to the three character blocks `:(!:`, `c99,` and `sch.` (though endian issues may reverse the order of the characters).

Does anyone know if there's any significance to these pointers?

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Yes, I *also* noticed the ASCII in Homer Simpson's 3d episode sequence, meaning I've been in this game *way* too long :-)

Comment: [explainxkcd.com](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/138:_Pointers) exists for this purpose but it doesn't look like a hidden meaning has been found

Comment: There is some inconclusive discussion [here](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?t=67496) and [here](http://blog.gg8.se/wordpress/2009/01/04/xkcd-binary-heart-transcriptionthe-sch-mystery/)

Comment: @kmdreko, that's *awesome!* I had no idea there was a site specifically for explaining the bizarre mind of one Randall Munroe :-)